# What is the syntax to define view/presenter pairs in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvp

Why is that when I define a view with data context in this way:

```
<views:MessageView DataContext="{x:Type presenters:MessagePresenter}"/>
```

that my MessagePresenter does not run its constructor?

What is the syntax to define view/presenter pairs like this in XAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

{x:Type} returns the type of MessagePresenter, not an instance of MessagePresenter.

The following creates an instance of MessagePresenter:

```
<views:MessageView>
    <views:MessageView.DataContext>
        <presenters:MessagePresenter/>
    </views:MessageView.DataContext>
</views:MessageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

`x:Type` is resolving a `Type` instance that represents the type in question (`MessagePresenter` in this case). It's not supposed to create an instance of the type.